# on click link open form and select a value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am thinking and thinking about this for a few weeks now , searching stack and google with no result, and maybe i am in a mindF and is it a stupid question but i hope some of you can help me

I have some posts in each post i have a link to the same form , in this form i have an option with 4 ore 5 value's to choose

each of these value's are matching with links in the posts

what i am looking for is :

On click link with value 1 auto select in form option value 1

is this possible ?

and how do i do it ?

**Sample of the links:**

```
<a title="" href="#" class="big-link" value="a" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true" data-animation="fade">Aanmelden</a>

<a title="" href="#" class="big-link" value="b" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true" data-animation="fade">Aanmelden</a>
```

**Sample of the form option:**

```
<label for="training">Training&amp;Workshops:</label> 
<select name="training" id="training" class="validate[required]">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>

</select>
```

the form opens in a jquery overlay "reveal"

thank you

Comment: use `data-*` attributes instead of invalid `A` > `value` attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/dep/1/edit

Something like:

```
<a title="" href="#" class="big-link" data-value="a">Aanmelden</a>
```

having this JS

```
$('.big-link').click(function( ev ){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).data('value');
  $('#training').val( val ); 
});
```

or like:

```
$('.big-link').click(function( ev ){
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#training').val( this.dataset.value ); 
});
```

Comment: Fantastic second one worked like a charm , thank you